# Keep dependencies scoped to `test` in lock.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I use sbt-lock plugin for dependency management, and have a problem: test dependencies in build.sbt, like

`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.+" % 
"test"`

are resolved as normal dependencies in lock.sbt, like

`"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.9"`

which leads to bigger library size when it's pushed to maven. How to keep "test" scope for such dependencies?

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/tkawachi/sbt-lock/issues/15